# Get Order Total before order is placed in payment_fields function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, point-of-sale

I'm using WooCommerce and the following plugin:
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-point-of-sale-pos/7869665

The following code should print a URL on the payment field which should open an app on the computer. All of this is working fine, but the URL needs to contain the total order price (in cents, so multiplied by 100) and I can't manage to get this done. I already wrote the following code and the only thing I'm missing is *$order_price_cents*.

```
public function payment_fields()
{

    $smartpinurl = "smartpin://payment?price=" . $order_price_cents . "&vat=zero&reference=Bestelling%20bij%DE-IT%20";

    echo '<a class="x-btn x-btn-rounded x-btn-regular" href="' . $smartpinurl . '" target="_blank">Activeer Smartpin App</a>';

}
```

Orders aren't placed yet when this button is clicked, so I can't use the default way to get the price.

E.g: I select a product worth €10.00 in the POS system. So $order_price_cents needs to be 1000.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm sorry, but I think I didn't make it clear enough that I'm using the following plugin for a Point Of Sale system: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-point-of-sale-pos/7869665

When an item is selected, it isn't stored in the default WC cart, but in the plugin's system.

Comment: This is a commercial plugin that we can't test… so sorry for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function payment_fields()
{

    global $woocommerce;  
    $order_price_cents = $woocommerce->cart->total * 100;

    $smartpinurl = "smartpin://payment?price=" . $order_price_cents . "&vat=zero&reference=Bestelling%20bij%DE-IT%20";

    echo '<a class="x-btn x-btn-rounded x-btn-regular" href="' . $smartpinurl . '" target="_blank">Activeer Smartpin App</a>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately the items you add in the POS plugin aren't stored in the WC cart but somewhere else (I don't know where and the plugin's support is very slow with answering tickets)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function payment_fields()
{    
    global $woocommerce;  
    $order_price_cents = $woocommerce->cart->total * 100;

    $smartpinurl = "smartpin://payment?price=" . $order_price_cents . "&vat=zero&reference=Bestelling%20bij%DE-IT%20";

    echo '<a class="x-btn x-btn-rounded x-btn-regular" href="' . $smartpinurl . '" target="_blank">Activeer Smartpin App</a>';

}
```

If it will not work properly so you can just check out the right replacement here for [**WooCommerce POS**](http://woopos.com/). This one is the best process for WooCommerce Point of Sale.